# Print address of virtual member function

Tags: c++, virtual, pointer-to-member, member-functions, vtable

I am trying to print the address of a virtual member function.
If I know which class implements the function I can write:

```
print("address: %p", &A::func);
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
A *b = new B();

printf("address: %p", &b->func); 
printf("address: %p", &b->A::func);
```

However this does not compile. Is it possible to do something like this, perhaps looking up the address in the vtable at runtime?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Currently there is no standard way of doing this in C++ although the information must be available somewhere. Otherwise, how could the program call the function? However, GCC provides an extension that allows us to retrieve the address of a virtual function:

```
void (A::*mfp)() = &A::func;
printf("address: %p", (void*)(b->*mfp));
```

...assuming the member function has the prototype `void func()`.
This can be pretty useful when you want to cache the address of a virtual function or use it in generated code. GCC will warn you about this construct unless you specify `-Wno-pmf-conversions`. It's unlikely that it works with any other compiler.

Answer (score 6):

Pointers to member functions are not always simple memory addresses.  See the table in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) showing the sizes of member function pointers on different compilers - some go up to 20 bytes.

As the article outlines a member function pointer is actually a blob of implementation-defined data to help resolve a call through the pointer.  You can store and call them OK, but if you want to print them, what do you print?  Best to treat it as a sequence of bytes and get its length via `sizeof`.

Comment: Yet the problem remains: how do you identify the function that get's called through a `virtual` call :) ?

Comment: That wasn't part of the question was it?  But I'd answer 'by calling it' :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this using a disassembler (https://github.com/vmt/udis86). The steps are:

1. Get a pointer to the virtual function via normal C++ code
2. Disassemble the `jmp` instruction at that address
3. Parse the real address from the disassembled string

Here is how I did it:

```
// First get the raw pointer to the virtual function
auto myVirtualFuncPtr = &MyClass::myFunc;
void* myVirtualFuncPtrRaw = (void*&)myVirtualFuncPtr;

// Resolve the real function!
void* myFuncPtr = resolveVirtualFunctionAddress(myVirtualFuncPtrRaw);

...

static void* resolveVirtualFunctionAddress(void* address)
{
    const int jumpInstructionSize = 5;

    static ud_t ud_obj;
    ud_init(&ud_obj);
    ud_set_mode(&ud_obj, sizeof(void*) * 8);
    ud_set_syntax(&ud_obj, UD_SYN_INTEL);
    ud_set_pc(&ud_obj, (uint64_t)address);
    ud_set_input_buffer(&ud_obj, (unsigned uint8_t*)address, jumpInstructionSize);

    std::string jmpInstruction = "";

    if (ud_disassemble(&ud_obj))
    {
        jmpInstruction += ud_insn_asm(&ud_obj);
    }

    // TODO: Implement startsWith and leftTrim yourself
    if (startsWith(jmpInstruction, "jmp "))
    {
        std::string jumpAddressStr = leftTrim(jmpInstruction, "jmp ");
        return hexToPointer(jumpAddressStr);
    }

    // If the jmp instruction was not found, then we just return the original address
    return address;
}

static void* hexToPointer(std::string hexString)
{
    void* address;
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << std::hex << hexString;
    ss >> address;

    return address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell in the standard, the only time you get dynamic binding is during a virtual function *call*. And once you've called a function, you're executing the statements within the function (i.e., you can't "stop halfway" into the call and get the address.)

I think it's impossible.

Comment: I suppose it's impossible portably, but knowing the implementation it should be possible to inspect the virtual table of an object at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't make a lot a of sense to me. If you have a normal function:

```
void f( int n ) {
}
```

then you can take its address:

```
f
```

but you cannot take the address of a function **call**, which is what you seem to want to do.

Comment: @GMan That's what I thought I said. Anyhow, I don't think this is possible.