# Output address of virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic object like so:

```
shared_ptr<Retirer> retirerObj(make_shared<Retirer>());
```

and I invoke its polymorphic method:

```
retirerObj->coat();
```

I'd like to get the address of where the `coat()` implementation is located. I tried a few ways using the address of operator, didnt work and then I wondered if I had to use some nasty syntax like for function pointers.

How can I output the address of `coat()`?

Comment: why would you need to save the address to a file? The vtable is implementation specific so this wouldn't be a safe operation, in addition to this not every polimorphic function is just an address. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068144/print-address-of-virtual-member-function

Comment: Without changing the function implementation, right?