# runtime-check whether an instance (Base*) override a parent function (Base::f())

Tags: c++, c++14, virtual-functions

How to determine whether a pointer of base (`B`) class is (polymorphism-ly) override a certain virtual function of the base class?

```
class B{
    public: int aField=0;
    virtual void f(){};
};
class C : public B{
    public: virtual void f(){aField=5;};
};
class D: public B{};

int main() {
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    std::vector<B*> bs;
    bs.push_back(&b);
    bs.push_back(&c);
    bs.push_back(&d);
    for(int n=0;n<3;n++){
        //std::cout<<(bs[n]->f)==B::f<<std::endl;
        //should print "true false true"
    }
}
```

I tried to compare the address of function pointer `bs[n]->f` against `B::f`, but it is uncompilable.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13878d869eeeef2a)

I feel that this question might be duplicated, but I can't find (sorry).

Comment: What are you trying to do here? This seems like an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218012)

Comment: @Justin  Mainly, because of curiosity.  I would like to know if it is possible ... it may useful for some rare cases of optimization (if I would happen to need it).

Comment: The question does not make much sense ;  since `f` is virtual, `bs[n]->f` is always a virtual call

Comment: Do you mean to ask: how to tell if `*bs[n]` has dynamic type `B` or not?

Comment: @M.M No, I just want to check whether a single certain function `f` is overridden.  e.g. `checkF(static_cast<B*>(new D()))` should return "It is not overridden". .... `D` can override other virtual function of `B`, but I don't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GCC has an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html#Bound-member-functions) that allows you to get the address of a virtual member function.

This can be used like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class B{
    public: int aField=0;
    virtual void f(){};
};
class C : public B{
    public: virtual void f(){aField=5;};
};
class D: public B{};

int main() {
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    std::vector<B*> bs;
    bs.push_back(&b);
    bs.push_back(&c);
    bs.push_back(&d);
    for(int n=0;n<3;n++){
        // This might need to be: (void*) B{}.*&B::f == (void*) (...)
        std::cout << ((void*) &B::f == (void*)(bs[n]->*&B::f)) << '\n';
    }
}
```

<sup>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e63dcd625c626f56)</sup>

You may find [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3068144/1896169) to be interesting.

Naturally, this is nonstandard behavior. If you wanted similar behavior in standard C++, you might actually be looking for *pure virtual* functions:

```
class B{
    public: int aField=0;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
```

Otherwise, you'd have to have some other mechanism to communicate, such as a `bool` return type on `f()`.